# "Error exited sync due to fetch errors android" while downloading Android Open Source Code

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to download the Android Open Source Code on my Linux system. I've executed the initial commands of mkdir, curl and repo init and then executed the repo sync command but after some time it showed "Error exited sync due to fetch errors android". Then I executed the repo sync command again but after some time it showed the following:

```
Downloading packages/apps/Settings:  75% (56MB/74MB)  Exception in thread Thread-150:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/ingrid/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 200, in _FetchHelper
    clone_bundle=not opt.no_clone_bundle)
  File "/home/ingrid/.repo/repo/project.py", line 968, in Sync_NetworkHalf
    and self._ApplyCloneBundle(initial=is_new, quiet=quiet):
  File "/home/ingrid/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1526, in _ApplyCloneBundle
    exist_dst = self._FetchBundle(bundle_url, bundle_tmp, bundle_dst, quiet)
  File "/home/ingrid/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1590, in _FetchBundle
    raise DownloadError('%s: %s ' % (req.get_host(), str(e)))
DownloadError: android.googlesource.com: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

Could you please tell me why it is showing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the project was partially synchronized and then your Internet connection has been interrupted. Thus, it was not possible to sync all the tree. After that you've tried to continue synchronization but due to the reason that some files already been downloaded you get these errors.

Try to delete your source folder and then reinit it once again. Sometimes it happens that Android sources cannot be synchronized.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try doing that.

Comment: You should not accept the answer until you're sure that it is correct )